# Cant print RollingOLS results

Tags: python, statsmodels

```
model = RollingOLS(endog=y,exog=X,window=21).fit()
print(model.summary())
```

X is structured like this:

| X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |
| . | . | . |

y is structured like this:

| y |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| . |
| . |
| . |

I want to get the RMSE of the model, but when I print model summary, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'RollingRegressionResults' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

When I replace it with

```
print(model.mse_model())
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Comment: What makes you think `model` has `summary` as an attribute, or that `mse_model` is something you can call?

Comment: @ScottHunter the following 2 links https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/regression_diagnostics.html and https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.rolling.RollingRegressionResults.html

Comment: There is no `summary` because it doesn't really make sense for a rolling regression given the multitude of estimates. The other quantities you are using are all properties, and so are directly available without calling.